# How can a qt + qml application display the same view via httpserver in parallel?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, httpserver

I have the following code to display a panel, periodically it receives data and displays it in a widget:

```
void QtMyPanel::startApp()
{

    //
    m_QmlEngine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/main.qml")));


    // Load new data

    //
    QTimer *ticker = new QTimer(this);
    connect(ticker, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(refreshPanelValues()));
    ticker->start(100);

    exec();
}
```

Everything works fine.

**My question is this:**

Is there a way to make the panel view display in parallel through httpserver, that is, when I go to 127.0.0.1:8080 I see the same as in the application?

I researched https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qhttpserver.html, but didn't find an answer there.

Comment: Your question is unclear, please provide more data. If you want to share the same date as you see in your application you have somehow make that available to the web server. There are lots of ways to that.

Comment: you have to reimplement everything. Qt does not provide anything remotely like a web framework.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of Qt technologies you should check out.

The first is WebGL. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/webgl.html. Which basically allows remote access to your application over the internet through a browser. Effectively, this is used for remote access, for example, if your Qt application access local hardware, Qt WebGL effectively allows remote access to your hardware.

The other is WebAssembly. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/wasm.html. This is effectively a compilation of your application using the Enscriptem WebAssembly target for delivering a near-native version of your application over the internet. Every client connecting to the website will download the WebAssembly and run your app natively in their web browser. The only caveat is are numerous limitations in that (1) threading is not widely supported, (2) networking is limited, (3) file access is limited, and (4) numerous components aren't supported.

Although it's a bit dated, you make like this YouTube video which explains Qt UI in a browser and includes WebGL and WebAssembly. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Q_8HkHdOXo